# How to append a value at the end of the char* argv[] array in C language?

Tags: c

How to append a value at the end of the (char* argv[]) array in C. Basically am trying to work on a problem where parent will pass the command line args(in argv[]) to the child for adding the numbers.Am creating a child for every two numbers and passing them in argv[]. Want to append the result sum returned from the child again to parent's to create child process until the number reduces to one.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Am trying to work on a problem where parent will pass the command line args(in argv[]) to the child for adding the numbers.Am creating a child for every two numbers and passing them in argv[]. Want to append the result sum returned from the child again to parent's to create child process until the number reduces to one.

Comment: If you add this details to your question by editing it I will be able to remove my down-vote.

Comment: Even if you do add something to argv in the child, the parent will not get this. You cannot pass information from child to parent in this way (the reason is that both are separate processes, and thus they do not share common memory).

Comment: I suggest printing the result of the client to stdout and read this in the parent.

Answer (score 4):

#### After the edit to the question

> Basically I am trying to work on a problem where parent will pass the command line args (in `argv[]`) to the child for adding the numbers.  I am creating a child for every two numbers and passing them in `argv[]`. I want to append the result sum returned from the child again to parent's to create child process until the number reduces to one.

This is not feasible; the memory of the child processes is completely separate from the parent process's memory.  The child cannot directly modify the parent's memory.  You will need to use some form of IPC (inter-process communication) to get information back from the child processes.

You can certainly pass the arguments to the children; that is (relatively) straight-forward.  However, you will need a mechanism such as a pipe for the parent to retrieve the answer from the child.

Note that this mechanism makes sense as a way to illustrate the issues involved in communicating between processes; it does not make sense as a way to add up numbers because the overhead of process startup and IPC is enormous compared to the cost of doing the work in a single program.

#### Before the edit to the question

> How to append a value at the end of the (char* argv[]) array in C.

Should you want to do so, you will have to:

1. Allocate a new array big enough for the extra value.
2. Copy the existing values from the old array to the new one.
3. Add your new value.
4. Ensure that the rest of the code uses the new values of `argc` and `argv` when appropriate.
5. Ensure that you release the new `argv` when it is no longer needed (unless your program is exiting or execing at the point when it is done with the new value, in which case, you don't need to free it).

In outline:

```
char **newv = malloc((argc + 2) * sizeof(*newv));
// Error check omitted
memmove(newv, argv, sizeof(*newv) * argc);
newv[argc] = new_value;
newv[argc+1] = 0;
argc++;
argv = newv;

...

free(newv);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try to create a new array and implement it.

Comment: What is the purpose of `newv[argc+1] = 0;`?

Comment: @DaveKennedy: The `argv` array has `argv[argc] == 0`; this assignment ensures that the same is true for the replacement array.

Comment: And each of the arguments is terminated by `\0` as well, right?

Comment: @DaveKennedy: Of course; they wouldn't be strings if they were not null terminated.  However, that is somewhat outside the scope of the answer; it simply works with the pointers; it just assumes `new_value` points to a string.

Comment: Ok, one more thing: why malloc `argc + 2`? Wouldn't `argc + 1` suffice?

Comment: @DaveKennedy: There needs to enough space for `argc+1` argument pointers plus the null pointer, hence `argc+2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100711/discussion-between-dave-kennedy-and-jonathan-leffler).

Answer (score 1):

In general you can't/shouldn't.

It's not defined how the system allocates this memory - you might be unlucky and it works on one system, but it might not on the next!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `argv` array in a child process does *not* change the array in the parent process. The OS makes a *copy* of the command line arguments in the child's address space. You will have to find another way to pass information from the child back to the parent.

Comment: Am not changing the argv array in child. Am exiting the sum from child and appending to the parent's argv directly. It looks like i should not do that. Thx for the repsonse anyways !

Comment: It is not possible for a child to "append to the parent's argv directly", and my answer explains why.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: You can't. The way C organizes memory does not allow it.

**Long Answer** (please correct me if I'm wrong)

In your function `int main(int, char**)` you get two variables passed. The first is a integer and the second is a pointer to a pointer (`char **` is almost the same as `char*[]`). You only know two things about this pointer:

1. `argv` points to `argc` pointers of type `char *` and all of them are stored one after the    other in memory (`argv + 1` points to the next pointer in memory if `argc > 1`).
2. Every pointer `argv + i` (`0 < i < argc` of course) consists of an unknown number of characters and a terminating `\0`.

You don't know

1. Where the memory is.
2. How to change it.

See the answer of one faster than me to see how you could do it: [How to append a value at the end of the char* argv[] array in C language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786552/how-to-append-a-value-at-the-end-of-the-char-argv-array-in-c-language/7786617#7786617)

Comment: Based on my negligible knowledge of C, technically it's `argv + sizeof(char*)`, not `argv + 1`.

Comment: Sure. That would be the exact address in integer arithmetic in pointer arithmetic you can just write `argv + 1` and your C compiler takes care of the rest (if you're not messing with `void*` pointers).